# Problem with saving NSDate to the CoreData context

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm trying to save managed object with one of the attribute's type Date to the `managedObjectContext`.

Code is like:

```
reminder.eventDate = selectedDate;
NSLog(@"Date: %@", selectedDate);
NSError *error = nil;
if (![reminder.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

during context saving program crashes with SIGABRT. Here is a console log:

```
2011-02-28 00:50:18.817 MyApp[9021:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e73490'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01057be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011ac5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x010596fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00fc9366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00fc8f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
```

Does anyone knows why I have that?
Second question is why when I check in debugger mode `selectedDate` isn't NSDate type but __NSDate (double underscore in front).

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I did some changes to easier catch the bug. so code now is like:

```
reminder.eventDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", selectedDate);
NSError *error = nil;
if (![reminder.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

so, here we save definitely NSDate. reminder.eventDate is NSDate too. But I still have this error. If I comment `reminder.eventDate = [NSDate date];` saving throws another error (date is mandatory field in NSData, so save: returns error "The operation couldn’t be completed." with `eventDate = nil;`.
CoreData structure is checked multiple times - eventDate has Date type.

**UPDATE (Problem solved):** Finally I found the problem. `eventDate` was set as key for the `detailTextLabel.text` in my tableview cells (I used KVO for that). So if was no direct call and I wasn't able to find any method invokation for the `eventDate`. Strange thing is that crash was on the `save` method, not later. And in the call stack there is no `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method at all...

Comment: Is there more to the crash log? It would be helpful to see where the comparison is starting from.

Comment: I've posted a crash log already. Or you wanted the full one? Anyway I found the problem (see update)

Comment: I wanted the full crash log, but since you figured it out it doesn't really matter anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to what has already been said:

It doesn't have to be a problem with the model or the NSManagedObject subclass. It could just be a piece of code almost anywhere that calls `isEqualToString:`. Somewhere you've got an object that the code assumes should be a NSString but is instead a NSDate object. I would look at any code that might convert dates to strings.

However, since it happens upon save I would look at any customizations you might have done to the subclass.

The place to start is by searching the project for `isEqualToString:`.

**Update:**

Since `isEqualToString` is a testing method it can be activated anytime you do a compare for a string such as in a sort. I couldn't reproduce your exact error but the following code does something similar:

```
id idDate=[NSDate date];
NSString *bob=[NSString stringWithString:@"bob"];
NSString *steve=@"test this";
steve=idDate;
NSLog(@"test=%@",([steve compare:bob]) ?@"YES":@"NO");
```

... complies but throws an exception:

```
-[NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4040
```

So, you can see how these types of errors can slip in. It's also a demonstration for why you should be careful with the use of `id`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find `isEqualToString:` in the project - 0 occurrences. If I select to find in "All Project and Frameworks" it finds 1 occurrence - in NSStrig.h

Comment: I found error finally and this answer describes the actual reason. Unfortunaly it didn't help me. Anyway bounty goes here ;)

Answer (score 7):

Silly as it sounds, I would suggest that you double check that both your reminder object and associated managedObjectContext are valid.

You are certain that your model correctly models eventDate as a date attribute, and you are also certain that the object you pass to the eventDate attribute is a NSDate object. So, try verifying that reminder and its managedObjectContext are not nil.

Finally, verify if all of the other attributes and relations are correctly set (check if you actually insert all of the required attributes and relations, check if the objects you use are of the correct type etc).

This will also help narrowing the possibilities.

**EDIT**: You can verifying what is actually happening inside your sqlite database. Simply add the following as an argument before starting your application:

-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1

see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html).

How you do this depends on your installed toolset (Xcode 3 or 4). I am using the latest Xcode 4 and to add an argument you simply select your current scheme, then you select Run "your app name" and click the Arguments tab to add the argument.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like you have your data model set up to expect a string in the eventDate property, rather than a date.

Comment: That is strange. Managed object class generated from the model has property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * eventDate;` and attribute type in data model is Data, not String.

Comment: check the `.xcdatamodel` file, not the `.m` file.

Comment: Here is my datamodel, as you can see eventDate is Date. Is there any way to check what was actually created in sqlite? http://ogreswamp.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Screen-shot-2011-02-28-at-08.44.38.png

Comment: Yes, there is one way. I have just edited my answer explaining how exactly you do this.

Answer (score 3):

NSDate is a "class cluster", which means that instances you actually deal with will be instances of some private subclass of NSDate (in this case, __NSDate).

As for the error, I agree with Simon Goldeen that the most likely reason is that the data model or the NSManagedObject subclass is expecting a string rather than a date.

Answer (score 0):

I chased this one too. Since your model and class definitions are good, and assuming your value is good, then there's one less obvious place that fixed it for me ... Delete the app from the device and clean your build, and make sure any seeded sqlite files are new too. My device or build folder had an old store or model lingering that caused this. What other frameworks are you using?  RestKit, JSON, etc?  Anything that overloads a class method could also be a suspect. ... hard to tell whats getting compared in that save ... My guess is an old store